# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Tags: php, if

```
        <?php
if ($st) 
{
'<div class="col-xl-8 order-xl-1">
          <div class="card bg-secondary shadow">
            <div class="card-header bg-white border-0">
              <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-8">
                  <h3 class="mb-0">Мой профиль</h3>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form action="profile-update-stat.php" method="POST" readonly>
                <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">Сведения участника конференции</h6>
                <div class="pl-lg-4">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="input-username">Логин</label>
                        <input type="text" id="input-username" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $userdata->user_login ?>" disabled >
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="input-email">Email адресс</label>
                        <input type="email" id="input-email" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="jesse@example.com" name="email" value="<?php echo $userdata->user_email ?>" disabled>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Выберете категорию участия</label>
                      <select class="form-control form-control-alternative" name="status" disabled>
                <option selected value="<?php echo $userdata->status ?>"></option>
                <option value="Студент">Студент</option>
                 <option  value="Выпускник">Выпускник</option>
                 <option  value="Партнер">Партнер</option>
              </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="my-4" />


                <!-- Description -->

                <div class="pl-lg-4">

                </div>
                <div class="col-2 text-right">
                  <button class="btn  btn-primary" href="location:http://alumnus.susu.ru/panel"> Продолжить </button> 
                </div>
              </form>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
'
} else 
{'
        <div class="col-xl-8 order-xl-1">
          <div class="card bg-secondary shadow">
            <div class="card-header bg-white border-0">
              <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-8">
                  <h3 class="mb-0">Мой профиль</h3>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form action="profile-update-stat.php" method="POST" readonly>
                <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">Сведения участника конференции</h6>
                <div class="pl-lg-4">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="input-username">Логин</label>
                        <input type="text" id="input-username" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $userdata->user_login ?>" disabled >
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="input-email">Email адресс</label>
                        <input type="email" id="input-email" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="jesse@example.com" name="email" value="<?php echo $userdata->user_email ?>" disabled>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Выберете категорию участия</label>
                      <select class="form-control form-control-alternative" name="status">
                <option selected value="<?php echo $userdata->movement ?>"></option>
                <option value="Студент">Студент</option>
                 <option  value="Выпускник">Выпускник</option>
                 <option  value="Партнер">Партнер</option>
              </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="my-4" />


                <!-- Description -->

                <div class="pl-lg-4">

                </div>
                <div class="col-2 text-right">
                  <button class="btn  btn-primary"> Сохранить</button> 
                </div>
              </form>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
'}

?>
```

Подскажите в чем проблемма, ни как не соображу... Ругается на ту что перед else. Спасибо!

Comment: перед `'<html>'` ставьте `echo '<html>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ругается потому что не понимает что вы написали

```
<?php
if ($st) {'321'}
 else {'123'}
```

Что бы это работало, как минимум нужно вот так(в вашем стиле):

```
<?php
if ($st) { echo '321'; }
 else { echo '123'; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Для отделения PHP кода от HTML нужно использовать тег `<?php` и завершающий `?>` . Пример:

```
<div class="content">
<?php
if ($something) {
?>
  <div class="content-example-true">
    <p>True</p>
  </div>
<?php
} else {
?>
  <div class="content-example-false">
    <p>False</p>
  </div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Однако я рекомендую Вам использовать шаблонизаторы, так как такой стиль написания кода снижает читабельность.